# Python: Getting a package's absolute path

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to navigate in the code having paths that are not hardcoded. I would like to know if there is a ROS/Python way of referring to a package's path. Something like `navigateToPackage("package_name")` is what I am after. Is this a supported feature? Does it exist?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330146/python:-getting-a-package%27s-absolute-path/) by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2019-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get the path of packages with the `rospkg`  python library: http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rospkg/html/python_api.html

```
import rospkg
rp = rospkg.RosPack()
package_path = rp.get_path('package_name')
```

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jägermeister](https://answers.ros.org/users/4624/j%C3%A4germeister/) on 2019-08-07**:
Worked like a charm, thank you.